# Is "set up another session" grammatically correct?

Tags: phrases

I tried to confirm an artist's schedule from a booking agent .

As the venue was fully booked, I had to propose an alternative date.

"... Just write to make sure if you mind I try to set up another session for the artists?"

I'd like to know if a native speaker would use the phrase "set up another session?"

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. WHO is making sure, the artists, you, or the agent?

Comment: Hi, Yu Chen, you have to say "if you don't mind" if you are asking for permission. Your question is not clear. Please edit your question after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Request for proof-reading is off-topic and please specify what is bothering you.

Answer (score 2):

"Set up another session" implies that you would like to add another date in addition to the previously discussed date.

E.g. if you originally booked for February 10th, then by saying "set up another session," you are saying you want to book them for February 10th and also another date.

"Set up an alternative session" would be better.

I'm not sure what "Just write to make sure if you mind I try to" means though.